# SonarQube properties defined in build gradle is not reflecting

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

Configured SonarQube properties in gradle.properties files for my spring boot project and  SonarQube analysis is working fine(able to verify in portal). But when it tried to add some more property in build.gradle, it is not reflecting in sonar portal .

...
For exmaple in build.gradle  added these property , which is not reflecting in sonar portal-->

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'gradle-boost' version '2.1.0'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
}
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "MyprojectName"
        property "sonar.projectDescription", "MyprojectDescription"
    }
}
```

...
Properties in gradle.properties file

```
# Sonar Configuration
systemProp.sonar.projectKey=com.acc.bt.radar:vom
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.login=515110c2760f20dadsdsadsad23434f6
```

Comment: As per latest Doc 8.4 [Link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/),it seems sonar.projectName taken from sonar DB and it can't be overridden in build.gradle .  If we need to override , we can specify the same in gradle.properties.

Answer (score 0):

As per latest Doc 8.4 [Link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/),it seems sonar.projectName taken from sonar DB and it can't be overridden in build.gradle . If we need to override , we can specify the same in gradle.properties.